# Norm of a projection in $L_p$

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $[0,1]$ and let us define the projection $P$ on $L^p(\mu)$: $$P \; \colon f \mapsto \mathbb{E}(f){\bf 1}$$ (where ${\bf 1}$ is the constant 1 function). What is the norm or a non-trivial estimate of the norm of $I-P$ if $p\neq 2$?

Comment: Isuggext you to start from [this paper](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDEQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsiba-ese.unisalento.it%2Findex.php%2Fnotemat%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F1536%2F1316&ei=PwpPU63MIOm84ASD-oCYCA&usg=AFQjCNGKL7vObyjGlnij1sIRG2UidgMVRA&sig2=rI5qWgo4A83ZLxCQgqojmQ&bvm=bv.64764171,d.bGE&cad=rjt) and then dig into referenced articles

Comment: If you'll find the answer, please post it here!

Comment: Mission is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here we go. Of course, $\|I-P\|_2=1$ because $I-P$ is an orthogonal projection in $L_2[0,1].$ Moreover, a simple calculation shows that $\|I-P\|_1=\|I-P\|_\infty = 2.$ Then a straightforward application of the Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem gives that 
$$ \|I-P\|_p \leq 2^{|1-{2\over p}|}.$$

(This reasoning can be found in a paper by S. Rolewicz.) The projection $I-P$ is actually the minimal projection to the hyperlane $X_p = \{ f : \mathbb{E}f = 0\} \subseteq L_p[0,1];$ i.e. it has the minimal norm among the projections with range $X_p.$ Later C. Franchetti showed in his paper 'The norm of the minimal projection onto hyperplanes in $L_p[0,1]$ and the radial constant' that 
  $$ \|I-P\|_p = \max_{0\leq x \leq 1} (x^{p-1} + (1-x)^{p-1})^{1/p}(x^{q-1} + (1-x)^{q-1})^{1/q},$$ where $1/p+1/q =1.$

Comment: very good research!